# CSS theme system in Wicket

Tags: wicket

I'm developing a Wicket 1.5 web application with many different components, and I'm interested to let the user choose between different themes (that means change the CSS styles of some components). So in some way I'll associate the chosen theme with the user session.

My question is, which is the best way to do this in Wicket?

Right now my components look like this:

```
public class SingleLayout extends Panel {

    public static final CssResourceReference CSS = new CssResourceReference(SingleLayout.class, "SingleLayout.css");

    public SingleLayout(...) {
        super(...);
    }

    protected CssResourceReference getCssResourceReference() {
        return CSS;
    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);
        response.renderCSSReference(getCssResourceReference());
    }

}
```

My ideal solution 'theme system' would:

- The components will have a CSS that works by default if the CSS of this component is not defined in the current theme.
- The components will also work in other applications without this theme system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not done this myself, but I would recomend to have a look at the [Session](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/Session.html) in Wicket. In the Javadoc, it explains the resource loading. Part of the search allgorithm is the Style, which is obtained from the users session.

Idea behind it, that you provide provide a css for each style (what you call a theme). The fallback to the standart theme isinluded.

Hope that helps.
Bert

Comment: Ok, thanks Bert. I'll have a close look at resource loading algorithm, and try to figure out a nice solution.